# Changing email registered with Runescape from an inactive address

Tags: runescape

My runescape account is connected to an email address that I disabled and now when I try to change it to an email that I use, I cannot get the second verification key. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to recover your old email temporarily so you could recover your password and change your account email?  I had a similar problem with Steam and fortunately my old email was still available.

Comment: Nope, gmail said that it cant be recovered because it was disabled 2 years ago.

Comment: When I say recover, I mean reregister under the same email address (if possible) to do this.  If the address is taken up or completely disabled, then not much could be done about that...

Answer (score 4):

Contact Runescape customer support. They may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I do not think there is anything you can do. I may be wrong but I don't think you can.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not work, but see if you can access the email account via [mail2web.com](http://mail2web.com/).